# How do I get at HTML attributes in nested tags with Mechanize in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

all. I'm having trouble getting at links in nested HTML with Mechanize in Python. Here's my current code (I've tried everything; this is just the latest copy, which doesn't work correctly) (and pardon my variable names (thing, stuff)):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(resultsPage)

if not soup.find(attrs={'class' : 'paging'}):
    print "Only one producted listed!"
else:   
    stuff = soup.find('div', attrs={'class' : 'paging'}).ul.li
    for thing in stuff:
        print thing
```

Here's the HTML I'm looking at:

```
<div class="paging">
<ul>
    <li><
    </li>
    <li class='on'>
        1-10
    </li>
    <li  class=''>
        <a id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_83a79912_01d8_4726_8a95_2953baaad0ec_ctl01_ucProductInfoPageNavigatorGroupTop_rptPageNavigators_ctl01_hlPage" href="http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/pages/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&amp;brandid=22&amp;searchtext=jell-o&amp;pageno=2">11-20</a>
    </li>
    <li  class=''>
        <a id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_83a79912_01d8_4726_8a95_2953baaad0ec_ctl01_ucProductInfoPageNavigatorGroupTop_rptPageNavigators_ctl02_hlPage" href="http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/pages/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&amp;brandid=22&amp;searchtext=jell-o&amp;pageno=3">21-30</a>
    </li>
    <li  class=''>
        <a id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_83a79912_01d8_4726_8a95_2953baaad0ec_ctl01_ucProductInfoPageNavigatorGroupTop_rptPageNavigators_ctl03_hlPage" href="http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/pages/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&amp;brandid=22&amp;searchtext=jell-o&amp;pageno=4">31-40</a>
    </li>
    <li  class=''>
        <a id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_83a79912_01d8_4726_8a95_2953baaad0ec_ctl01_ucProductInfoPageNavigatorGroupTop_rptPageNavigators_ctl04_hlPage" href="http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/pages/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&amp;brandid=22&amp;searchtext=jell-o&amp;pageno=5">41-50</a>
    </li>
    <li  class=''>
        <a id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_83a79912_01d8_4726_8a95_2953baaad0ec_ctl01_ucProductInfoPageNavigatorGroupTop_rptPageNavigators_ctl05_hlPage" href="http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/pages/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&amp;brandid=22&amp;searchtext=jell-o&amp;pageno=6">51-60</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_83a79912_01d8_4726_8a95_2953baaad0ec_ctl01_ucProductInfoPageNavigatorGroupTop_lnkNext" href="http://www.kraftrecipes.com/products/pages/productinfosearchresults.aspx?catalogtype=1&amp;brandid=22&amp;searchtext=jell-o&amp;pageno=7">>></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to determine whether or not there are `<li>` tags with hyperlinks in them; if there are I need to store them for clicking on later. This is the page that the code came from, in case you're curious: http://www.kraftrecipes.com/Products/ProductInfoSearchResults.aspx?CatalogType=1&BrandId=22&SearchText=Jell-O&PageNo=1 I'm working on something to scrape food websites for product info and I need to be able to navigate around the search results.

I have another quick side question. Is it bad to chain together tags and searches like this?

```
ingredients = soup.find(attrs={'class' : "TitleAndDescription"}).div.find(text=re.compile("Ingredients")).next
```

I'm just learning Python but this seems kind of kludge-y and I'd like to know what you guys think. Here's a sample of the HTML I'm scraping:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="contHeader" class="TitleAndDescription">
                <h1>JELL-O - GELATIN DESSERT - RASPBERRY</h1>
                <div class="textArea">
                    <strong>Ingredients:</strong> SUGAR, GELATIN, ADIPIC ACID (FOR TARTNESS), CONTAINS LESS THAN 2% OF ARTIFICIAL FLAVOR, DISODIUM PHOSPHATE AND SODIUM CITRATE (CONTROL ACIDITY), FUMARIC ACID (FOR TARTNESS), RED 40.<br/>
                    <strong>Size:</strong> 6 OZ<br/><strong>Upc:</strong> 4300020052<br/>
                    <br/>
                    <!--<br/>-->
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            ...
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Sorry for the wall of text. Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"HTMLParser" module of python could be one of the solution to the problem. Find more details at http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want to get is the list of all `li` tags that contain any `a` tag (no matter how deep in the DOM tree). If that's correct, then you can do something like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(resultsPage)
list_items = [list_item for list_item in soup.findAll('li')
              if list_item.findAll('a')]
```